# Controlling elements depending on the checked state of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a code in which I want to show and hide things, depending on the checked state of the checkboxes.

**My HTML code**

```
<div class="row checks">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="partial-vaccinated" class="partial-check" checked>
            <label for="level-of-vaccination">Partially Vaccinated</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fully-vaccinated" class="fully-check">
            <label for="level-of-vaccination">Partially Vaccinated</label>
          </div>
        </div>
<div class=".form-block">I want to hide this(for example)</div>
```

**My Javascript code**

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click',function(){
    $("input:checkbox").not(this).prop('checked', false);
})

$(".partial-check, .fully-check").on('click', function(){
    $(".form-block").slideToggle(500);
})
```

So this javascript code works, BUT , when I click the checkbox for fully vaccinated label, I want the form block-to hide, which is not happening. It is only when I click the partially vaccinated checkbox, that I see the toggle behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class=".form-block">I want to hide this(for example)</div>
```

should be

```html
<div class="form-block">I want to hide this(for example)</div>
```

A class name can only start with an underscore, hyphen or a letter from a-z. A period is an invalid class name.

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click',function(){
    $("input:checkbox").not(this).prop('checked', false);
})

$(".partial-check, .fully-check").on('click', function(){
    $(".form-block").slideToggle(500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row checks">
          <div class="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="partial-vaccinated" class="partial-check" checked>
            <label for="level-of-vaccination">Partially Vaccinated</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="fully-vaccinated" class="fully-check">
            <label for="level-of-vaccination">Partially Vaccinated</label>
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-block">I want to hide this(for example)</div>
```

Comment: If checked for fully vaccinated label then **form-block** should be **hide** but your snippet form-block **showing**.